# RVM can't install ruby on MacOS

Tags: ruby, rvm

I type this command :

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Then i press "Ctrl+Z", So RVM is exit.

But When i type command again,[image: ruby install error]

It's stop here...
So, How to resolve it , and install ruby right way?

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? Try installing the packages manually to see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step depends on the bandwidth of your internet connection and configuration of your machine and can take upto 15 - 30 minutes. This first downloads(Bandwidth) the ruby binaries and then compiles(CPU + RAM dependent) it.

Also, in your case, its updating system packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add `--with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr` - rvm handles this for you automatically.

As for the process - it takes long but should finish in less then hour (on slow internet connection and computer it could be few).

If the process does not show any changes in like 15 minutes you can try two things:

1. open another console/tab and monitor processes with `top`, on the top of list you should see something like `ruby`, `curl`, `cc1`, `make` ... but anything with more then 10-20% in the `%CPU` column will indicate - work is done.
2. break the process (`CTRL+C`) and start it again with:

   ```
   rvm install 2.0.0 --debug
   ```

   now it will show more details about what is going on - including log files where all outputs are redirected, you can watch those log files in other console with `less` (to see from start to current position) or `tee -f` (to see the changes as they happen)

Answer (score 0):

Also just noticed the `CTRL+Z` - this can be holding some processes that block RVM - try running `fg 1` - it should start the stopped process.

For more information about `CTRL+Z` vs. `CTRL+C` see https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I just restart my mac,then install again,that's all

Comment: that's hard way to recover from from `CTRL+Z` - it would be easier to `fg 1` ;)

Answer (score -2):

To echo Nerve's answer and depa - I am fuzzy on why installing with RVM is such a pain - but Homebrew is going to be your best friend when it comes to doing the installations. I had trouble too.

Here is a link to a set up tutorial that i followed: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/environment/environment.html

Make sure homebrew (http://brew.sh/) is installed and if this is your first set up, try looking through the tutorial on set up and seeing if you missed anything

if that doesn't do it - some back and provide more information on what you've done so far and already have set up!

Comment: downvoted - rvm does just all the steps internally so you do not have to follow any tutorial and solve any problems by yourself - it will take relatively longer because now you have no work for yourself when al is done for you, go grab an coffee, take a break.